# Forbid implicit casting of compatible types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Are there any way to forbid implicit casting of compatible types in typescript?

```
class A{}
class B{}
function foo(a:A,b:B){}

foo(new B(),new A()) // valid even in strict mode ?!!
```

Comment: Just use `class A { tag='A' } class B { tag='B' }`

Comment: TS has a structural type system; two empty classes are structurally identical and thus mutually assignable.  You need to break the structural compatibility by adding incompatible properties.  For classes specifically you can add `private`/`protected` properties which emulate nominal typing.  See the answers to the linked questions for more information.

Comment: I ended up doing `class A { private tag='' }`